# Recording indicator sound getting recorded

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I initiate a recording, I have a sound effect play to indicate the recording started.  I'm current implementing a 1 second delay to avoid recording the recording indicator sound.

```
//Play the sound
[self.defaultPlayer play];

//Create the delay
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

//Record
[self.recorder record];

});
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AVAudioPlayer object for playing the sound, set it's delegate to self, and implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

Where you can call:

```
[self.recorder record];
```

I think this is a nice way to make the system nicely syncronize everything.

Comment: I'm actually using two `AVAudioPlayers`.  One player for the recording indicator sound and another player for the play back of the audio recording.  How can I implement `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` to respond only to the recording indicator player?

Comment: Well, you can make the recording indicator player to be a property (if not done this thing yet). DON'T FORGET to set the delegate property of that player to self. Then, inside the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: method, simple compare if (player == self.recordingIndicatorPlayer) { /*...*/ }